# Why can't I change the variables x and y to 0? (x and y are snake head coords)

Tags: javascript

When x and y are reaching the end of the canvas, they aren't changing to 0, they keep increasing. The size of canvas is 300 x 300. When I change the position of x and y to a number like 1, it is changing.
I tried a lot of things, but it doesn't work. Even by changing their value to 0 in Chrome Console, they remain the same.

```js
let x = 150, y = 150;
/* main game loop */ {
    // ...
    if (x >= canvas.width) {
        x = 0;
    }
    if (x <= 0) {
        x = canvas.width;
    }
    if (y >= canvas.height) {
        y = 0;
    }
    if (y <= 0) {
        y = canvas.height;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There are some significant readability issues with this code. Please use descriptive variable names, and reduce the code to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A modicum of debugging will help both by probably making it clear what the issue is, and even if not it still helps you to reduce the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use *else if*.
This should fix it:

```
            if (x >= canvas.width) {
                x = 0;
            }
            else if (x <= 0) {
                x = canvas.width;
            }
            if (y >= canvas.height) {
                y = 0;
            }
            else if (y <= 0) {
                y = canvas.height;
            }
```